# Why can't I seem to connect to a Minecraft server through Remobo?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, networking

I'm using [Remobo](http://www.remobo.com/) to connect to a server but when I try to connect in Minecraft it'll just time out.

Comment: Is the server up?

Comment: I never managed to get Remobo to work either.

Comment: Make sure the person who is hosting the server has port forwarded.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the basics (make sure the server is up, make sure you can ping the server, etc), have whoever is running the server make sure that it's not bound to a particular IP address.  Basically, when the server starts up, you (or whoever's running it) should see the following line in the console:

```
[INFO] Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
```

If it says anything else other than ***:25565** there, then the server is binding to a particular IP.  Ask your server admin if they can try changing the **server-ip** line of the **server.properties** configuration file to their Remobo IP address (which I believe begins with 7.x.x.x -- not sure) or just blanking it out -- so the file should have **one** of the two following lines:

```
server-ip=
 (or)
server-ip=7.32.72.135
```

Of course, replace "7.32.72.135" with the server's Remobo IP address :)

The potential downside to this is that the server may no longer accept connections directly through the router (i.e. if the admin had the server IP set to their public IP address, the MC server may no longer recognize connections coming in directly from the internet, and all users would need to connect using Remobo).